# mocking EF without repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, orm

I'm using Entity Framework 4.

I have read this post:

http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/mocking-entity-framework-data-context

But in my code I don't see anything like  `EFContext` `Attach() Detach()` and other stuff that appears there.

Mine is more like this diagram:

http://blogofrab.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/maintenance-free-mocking-for-unit.html

and then I don't understand how mocking the Icontext will help mocking?

The ORM to the DB lays inside `get property` and `AddTo methods`

Comment: are you using code first or database/model first? Have you read the whole blog post? EFContext class is created by the author of the post and the code is there. Attach and Detach are also added as methods on the mock.